# How to send data back from the class library to the web form application while being processed in the library?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, webforms, console-application

I have created a web form application. It's main purpose is to copy files. I have also created a class library and written the main logic for copying there. I wanted to show what file is being currently copied in my web form. But I can't get the data back from the class library to show it without stopping the copying process. How do I get the data back?

I tried the same thing in console application, there I can show the files that are being copied directly on the console using Console.WriteLine().

Please help me as I am learning .Net now.

Comment: Your library needs to accept a way of proving progress updates. This is generally done by passing a callback/object implementing an interface (such as IProgress) to the method in question that is being called each time it starts processing a file. Inside that callback/object you can do whatever you want. An alternative would be to expose an event on the object doing the copying that is being raised when you start copying a file.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide your code that you want help with. A simplified version should be enough.